# Creating a new BlackBerry Eclipse Project from SVN

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am trying to import BlackBerry code and into Eclipse from SVN. It isn't checked in as an project, so I am checking it out using the New Project Wizard. Unfortunately, this only gives me a blank project. How can I get round this?

- Windows 7
- Eclipse 3.4.1
- JDE Component Package 4.7
- BlackBerry  JDE Plugin 1.0.0.67

**Related Questions:**

- Investigating importing into already existing projects [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339140/importing-files-from-subversion-into-an-existing-project)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't been working with BlackBerry development lately, but, If you installed correctly the BlackBerry JDE Plugin for Eclipse, you should have a "BlackBerry" menu item in Eclipse, where you can find everything you need related to BB development. I'm not sure, but I believe there is a "New project" sub-option or something similar in that menu item.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I can create a new BlackBerry project, but then I don't know how to get Subversion to get the files into it

Comment: I'd checkout the SVN files myself through TortoiseSVN or the command-line client and then import them to the project inside Eclipse. I know there are Eclipse plugins for SVN integration, but I'd try this as another option.

Comment: Subclipse actually managed to recognise the files I checked out using Tortoise

Comment: This method works in 1.1 or greater. Unfortunately, it only produces an empty project in 1.0