# Importing files from Subversion into an existing project

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I am trying to import files from a SVN repository into an existing Eclipse project using Subclipse. Unfortunately, I can only find a way to create a new project from a repository. I know about Tortoise SVN, but it is so much easier to remember to add files when version control is imported into the IDE. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't seem to offer this functionality, but you can use another svn client to achieve this effect and then subversion will recognise that these files are under version control.

You may also want to check out how to [check out the contents rather than the folder itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927806/svn-checkout-the-contents-of-a-folder-not-the-folder-itself).